# unpersisted related documents in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Say I have a post document with many replies.  When I remove those replies in memory, I want to be able to see that those replies have been removed, although unpersisted.  Let me show you:

```
class Post
    has_many :replies, class_name: 'PostReply', autosave: true
end

post.replies.count
 => 3
post.replies = []
 => [] 
post.replies.last 
 => #<Post...>
# (also note that at this point, #count will return 3 and #length will return 0.)
```

I would further expect this behavior to change with the Identity Map turned on.  E.g., the final line would be using replies from memory, and return nil.

What is incorrect in my thinking & assumptions here?  How can I get the desired behavior?  And a bonus question, where can I see logs showing DB queries from IRB?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your model definition. Are replies really embedded or referenced?

Comment: Oh good call, these are referenced with `has_many`

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ORMs/ODMs, but I think that `replies` is no ordinary array. You can't just assign empty value to it. I might be completely wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the inverse relation:

```
class Post
  has_many :replies, class_name: "PostReply", autosave: true, inverse_of: :post
end

class PostReply
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :replies
end
```